# How to "defile" text using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First, I'm a very newbie on jQuery.
What I want actually is :

- To have a list of sentences
- The color of those sentences is black for example
- jQuery to make sentences change color (the current would be red for example) and make this effect goes from one sentence to the next one.

This is my very simple example :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  myVar = setInterval(alertFunc, 3000);
});

function alertFunc() {

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $("#" + i).css("color", "rgb(255,194,0)"); //this is the color of the current li and it loops to the next one..ect
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 30pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="line" id="1">one</li>
  <li class="line" id="2">two</li>
  <li class="line" id="3">three</li>
</ul>
```

It would be very nice if someone helps me, I'm sincerely trying to make it works for hours and no results.

Comment: Do you want only one line at colored at a time and two other black or color all the lines

Comment: Hi Mr.Arjun, yes i want only one line colored at a time

Comment: Hi @Tushar Your answer was very helpful but i don't know why did you remove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may suffice!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  i =1;
  $("#" + i).css("color", "rgb(255,194,0)"); //sets line of first color initially just once
  i++;
  myVar = setInterval(alertFunc, 3000);
  
});

function alertFunc() {
  
    $(".list li.line").css("color", "rgb(0,0,0)"); //resets the color of all lines to black
    $("#" + i).css("color", "rgb(255,194,0)"); //this is the color of the current li and it loops to the next one..ect
  if(i==3){
    i=1;
}else{
  i++;
  }
  }
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 30pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="line" id="1">one</li>
  <li class="line" id="2">two</li>
  <li class="line" id="3">three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.delay`, `delay()` works with the `animation (fx) queue`.

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  $("#"+i)
  .delay(i*400)
  .queue(function (next) { 
    $(this).css("color", "rgb(255,194,0)"); 
    next(); 
  });
}
```

If it looks complicated, use plain `setTimeout`

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#"+i).css("color", "rgb(255,194,0)");
  }, i*400);
}
```